# Is it possible to define a callback function parameter as a namespaced interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript, definitelytyped

I am creating some intellisense for a set of application specific APIs and am curious if its possible to define the parameter of a callback function as a previously defined interface? I fear that I am incapable of even asking this question properly so I will instead just show you the code.

I have a definitelyTyped file that contains my typescript defined intellisense. Its quite long so I will only show what is relevant.

```
declare interface N_search {
    create: {
        (options: {
            type: string
        }): N_search.Search
}

declare namespace N_search {

    interface Search {
        run(): N_search.ResultSet
    }
    interface Result {
        type: string
        id: number
    }
    interface ResultSet {
        each: {
            (callback (N_search.Result)) : void //aware this is not correct...
    }
```

It might be hard to gather from that mess but the (callback) inside of the interface ResultSet is a function. The parameter for that function is a N_search.Result object and I want the intellisense to show this. This is the javascript I am looking to get intellisense for.

```
var search = N_search.create(options);

search.run().each(function (result) {
    result. /* I want intellisense here to show the N_search.Result object
      which should be type: string  ;  id: number */
});
```

I hope my question makes sense, and I greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Does `callback = () => N_search.Result` not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your `ResultSet` interface like:

```
interface ResultSet {
    each: (callback: (result: N_search.Result) => void) => void        
}
```

Comment: I am embarrassed to say how much time I spent trying to figure this out! You sir have ensured I will be able to sleep tonight :)

Comment: We have all been there :) Nothing to be embarrassed about.